# VS2010 error LNK2001: unresolved external in MFC static application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, linker, lnk2001

I get this error in Visual Studio 2010 SP1, when I try to link a static MFC application with the libmp3lame.lib C++ library.

```
>nafxcwd.lib(appcore.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___argv
>nafxcwd.lib(appcore.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___argc
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're linking against the correct version of the runtime library (Multithreaded, Multithreaded DLL, Debug Multithreaded, Debug Multithreaded DLL etc).

Comment: Yes I am linking the correct lib files, the project is mfc static